# Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies:

Tags: grails

1. I updated a plugin to use cxf 2.0.3 - previously the plugin was using cxf 1.4.7.

Following is the updated buildconfig of the plugin.

```
plugins {
    // starting with Grails 2.3 the tomcat plugin is not updated/released along with Grails, so hard code version
    build(":tomcat:2.2.5",
            ":release:2.2.1",) {
        export = false
    }

    compile ":cxf-client:2.0.3"
}
```

2. When my application tries to load the plugin, I get the following error.
   I tried using the plugin on an existing project and new project and still get the error.

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....
|Compiling 1 source files
..........................................................Error 
|
Error: The following plugins failed to load due to missing dependencies: [msApi]
- Plugin: msApi
   - Dependencies:
       ! cxf-client (Required: 1.4.7, Found: 2.0.3) [INVALID]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

3. Is there some cache file I need to delete?

Answer (score 0):

Search for string: "1.4.7" in whole plugin project f.e. by `grep -rn "1.4.7"` and you will find all occurences of this string in project (and then you will decide to change it or to delete such a file from result).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I found 1.4.7 in the following files which I updated to 2.0.3.                                                                                                                                                                           MsApiGrailsPlugin.groovy:    def dependsOn = ['cxf-client' : "1.4.7"]
plugin.xml:      <plugin group='org.grails.plugins' name='cxf-client' version='1.4.7' />